# Java LocalDateTime being converted into an array of ints when being converted to JSON using Spring boot rest

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, jackson

My code is as below

```
@Data 
@Document(collection = "models")
public class Model {
  @Field(value = "modelDt")
  private LocalDateTime modelDate;
}

@Data
public class ModelDTO {
  private LocalDateTime modelDate;
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/model")
public class ModelController {

  @Autowired 
  ModelService modelService;

  @GetMapping
  public List<ModelDTO> getModels() {
    return modelService.getAllModels();
  }
}
```

Used this almost everywhere where the JSON response is coming as a proper format like yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00 , but in the above case I'm getting the date in the below format.

```
[
  {
    "modelDate": [
    YYYY,
    MM, 
    DD, 
    00,
    00,
    0000
    ]
  }
]
```

I've crossed checked my code with the ones where the proper format is being returned.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

use below Jackson annotation on date fields

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: This worked. Why is it that in the above case it is required but other models didn't require any such annotation. Is there a way you can avoid this annotation and still get the desired result?

Comment: @Pi53 Can you show the models for which it's working automatically?

Comment: I bet there is no models for which it's working automatically!

Answer (score 4):

If you want LocalDateTime to always serialize in any format then follow the solution.

You can create a Serializer for LocalDateTime and add it `ObjectMapper`.Then always LocalDateTime serialize using `JacksonLocalDateTimeSerializer`.

```
public class JacksonLocalDateTimeSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1355852411036457107L;

  private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter =
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

  public JacksonLocalDateTimeSerializer() {
    this(null);
  }

  protected JacksonLocalDateTimeSerializer(Class<LocalDateTime> type) {
    super(type);
  }

  @Override
  public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
      SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator.writeString(formatter.format(value));
  }

}
```

And add this in `ObjectMapper` to auto-apply for `LocalDateTime` field for all responses.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper() {
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new JacksonLocalDateTimeSerializer());
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```